# Vue Js not updating from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

Im grabbing this JSON object and passing it on to this Vue. However, It is not updating on my page, but the object is there since window.alert(jobj.Name) works fine.  Here is my vue and my view.

```
var app2 = new Vue({
el: '#menuPage',

data: {
    HeaderTitle: 'NOT CHANGED',
    content_body: 'test body',
},
methods: {
    loadMENU: function (jobj) {

        app2 = this;
        window.location.href = "tools/menu.html"; //relative to domain

        window.alert(jobj.Name);
        this.HeaderTitle = jobj.Name;

    }
} }); 




  <div id="menuPage">{{HeaderTitle}}</div>
```

It is only showing "NOT CHANGED" Instead of the object Name.

Comment: Trying to understand your code sample ... it seems odd to me to change location.href and then set this.HeaderTitle. Does this code run on the menu.html page and, if so, is it possible that you're re-loading the page (by setting location.href) and thus resetting the Vue object to its initial state? Does it work if you comment out the window.location.href line?

Comment: The reason Im changing the href is because Im on a different page, "login.html. so in another part of the code I 1. Authenticate login, when it returns true (it does) I call app2.loadMENU(data); , where data is a JSON object. I then load the Menu.html page and update all the information in there. I am able to load the page, but as mentioned above it does not update information. it only shows the preset 'NOT CHANGED'

Comment: Okay, I think I kind of understand. When you set location.href, you're making the browser to navigate to a new page, which wipes out any state from the current page. If this same script runs on the new page, it will create a brand new Vue instance (and HeaderTitle will have the initial value of 'NOT CHANGED').

Comment: I believe you are right. Do you recommend any other way of achieving what I am doing?

Comment: @GuiCosta you need to use vue-router to navigate about your SPA.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the method. You should use a button to trigger the method.

html

```
<div id="menuPage">{{HeaderTitle}}
  <button v-on:click="loadMENU">button</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var app2 = new Vue({
el: '#menuPage',

data: {
    HeaderTitle: 'NOT CHANGED',
    content_body: 'test body',
},
methods: {
    loadMENU: function () {

        app2 = this;
        const herf = window.location.href; 
        window.alert(herf);
        this.HeaderTitle = herf;

    }
} });
```